# Returning co-ordinates from a grid

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have 6x6 grid and I am trying to return the co-ordinates of each character in the grid from a string.

My thoughts were to:

1. Convert the string to a list of characters.
2. Enumerate through the grid to check if the characters exist.
3. Print the co-ordinates of all the characters ??

Here is my code(doesn't work):

```
grid = [
        ["A","B","C","D","E","F"],
    ["A","8","3","P","S","2","Z"],
    ["B","7","T","O","R","1","Y"],
    ["C","6","Q","N","M","0","X"],
    ["D","5","G","L","K","U","W"],
    ["E","4","9","I","H","J","V"],
    ["F","C","E","B","F","A","D"]
    ]

print("Please enter a message to encode:")
message = raw_input()

lst = list(message)

search = lst

for rownum, row in enumerate(grid):
    for colnum, value in enumerate(row):
        if value == search:
            print "(%d,%d)" % (rownum, colnum)
```

What I am trying to achieve is if  you inputed "hello" it would return ED FC DC DC BC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is to eschew the list-of-lists and simply store the ordered characters in a string. Then, use `str.index` to get the 0-based position of the character, and finally develop a function to turn that index into your coordinates, using division and a modulus

Answer (score 2):

Rather than searching through the whole `grid` for each character, you would be better pre-processing your grid to get the locations, creating a dictionary mapping each character to its location:

```
locations = {}
for x in range(1, len(grid)): # note offset for label row
    for y in range(1, len(grid[x])-1): # and label column
        locations[grid[x][y]] = (grid[0][y-1], grid[x][0])
```

Note the `grid[0][y-1]` in the last line; the first row in your list is shorter than the others. Alternatively, you could pad it with `None` or an empty string `""` and remove the `-1`:

```
grid = [[None, "A", "B", ...], ...]
```

This creates a dictionary in the form `{character: (column, row)}`:

```
 locations == {'P': ('C', 'A'), 'Q': ('B', 'C'), ...}
```

Then you can easily get the row and column:

```
for c in lst:
    col, row = locations[c]
```

It is worth noting that you need to convert the characters input into upper case, otherwise you will get a `KeyError` (as lower-case characters aren't in your grid):

```
lst = list(raw_input("Please enter a message to encode: ").upper())
```